# Automatic update of textbox value based on last value in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

[image]
I have these in a worksheet

[image]

Then on a userform, I want that as I change the chapter, the No. part automatically updates that if on the worksheet, Chapter 1 last No. is 1 so No. on the userform automatically updates to 2, then same with Chapter 2 and 3.

This is what I tried:

```
    Dim label As Control
    For ctr = 1 To InfoForm.Chapter.ListCount - 1
        For Each label In InfoForm.Controls
            If TypeName(label) = "Label" Then
                i = i + 1
                Dim WhatChapter As String
                WhatChapter = InfoForm.Chapter
                lastNum = Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                If WhatChapter = "Chapter " & ctr Then
                    If Cells(lastNum, i).Value = "No." Then
                        Num.Value = 1
                    Else
                       Num.Value = Cells(lastNum, i).Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next ctr
```